# how can Click on small figures in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I has series like this

```
        series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 19552.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
```

you can see that I has small points (29.9, 71.5) in this series and other (19552.1) has larger than small point

that make I cant click in small point

how can I deal with this problem

you can see this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xLcmojzr/) to know what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about to use logarithmic yAxis

http://jsfiddle.net/xLcmojzr/2/

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({

    title: {
        text: 'Logarithmic axis demo'
    },

    xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 1
    },

    yAxis: {
        type: 'logarithmic',
        minorTickInterval: 0.1
    },

    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br />',
        pointFormat: 'x = {point.x}, y = {point.y}'
    },

    series: [{
        data: [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512],
        pointStart: 1
    }]
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Or You could set a minimum length for the columns using the ´minPointLength´ option

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.events.click

```
minPointLength: 0,
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xLcmojzr/3/)